# Image not displaying in img src in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am able to click photos in my phone but image not displaying on my page.
I have installed the plugins from official ionic framework doc:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera
```

This is my code:

```
 getPic()
  {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 70,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {         
     this.myPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {         
    });
  }
```

I have declared  `myPhoto:any;` inside my class.

This is where I am showing my Image:

```
<ion-content no-bounce padding>   
<button ion-button (click)="getPic()">Take A Picture</button>
<p align="center"><img src="{{ myPhoto }}"></p>
</ion-content>
```

I don't know where I am doing the mistake. Please Help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private OpenCamera(): void{
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation: true,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

  this.AddIssueObj.file.push(s);
  this.uploadcount=this.AddIssueObj.file.length;
}, (err) => {
  // Handle error
});
```

}

for HTML:

```
 <ion-scroll scrollX="true" class="m-slider__scroll" scroll-avatar>
          <span *ngFor="let v of photoList">
            <img src="{{v}}" alt="slider image1" class="m-slider__img" />
          </span>
        </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: this.myphoto=imagedata;

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Rashmi ranjana. But please tell me what is wrong in my code? Why it is not displaying in mypage? Do I have to change `this.myPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;` to this `this.myphoto=imagedata;`

Comment: yes. please upvote my answer if it helped you. What ever i experienced is you cant not display base64 image in ionic.

Comment: Yes Exactly. How do I do that? How do I display that base64image?

Comment: you can not display base 64 image. you need native path which you will get in imagedata. you need to display that in html. just change you code from this.myPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData; to this this.myphoto=imagedata;